# Calling a function from a struct (C/Assembly)

Tags: c, assembly, struct

I'm trying to port some code from C to assembly but I'm running into some trouble here. In the c function I get passed a struct. Inside this struct there are saved two functions like this:

```
typedef struct sort sort_t;
struct sort {
    void *data;
    cmpfunc_t cmpfunc;
    cpyfunc_t cpyfunc;
};
```

In the C code these functions are called like this (m being a pointer to the struct):

```
m->cpyfunc(m->data, j, k);
```

Now I'm trying to do this in assembly. I've realized that structs are saved sequentially in memory. So if m was stored in %ebx then cmpfunc would be found in 4(%ebx). But I can't figure out how to call this function from assembly. I've tried both running directly from 4(%ebx) by doing:

```
call    *4(%ebx)
```

That wouldn't work so I tried:

```
movl    4(%ebx),%edx
call    *%edx
```

But to no avail. I can't seem to find any way to do this and any searching I've tried have turned up nothing. How would I do this in Assembly?

Comment: Which assembler do you use, and why are there asterisks before your call address?

Comment: How about compiling and seeing the generated assembly.

Comment: @Leeor That's GAS-style assembler, and because it's required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little test program:

```
typedef void (*cpyfunc_t)(void *, int, int);
typedef void (*cmpfunc_t)(void);
struct sort {
    void *data;
    cmpfunc_t cmpfunc;
    cpyfunc_t cpyfunc;
};


int main()
{
    struct sort *m;
    int k,j;

    m->cpyfunc(m->data, j, k);
}
```

and compiled with the [ELLCC demo](http://ellcc.org/demo). I got this:

```
    .file   "/tmp/webcompile/_31142_0.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %edi
    pushl   %esi
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    -12(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    8(%ecx), %ecx
    movl    -12(%ebp), %edx
    movl    (%edx), %edx
    movl    -20(%ebp), %esi
    movl    -16(%ebp), %edi
    movl    %edx, (%esp)
    movl    %esi, 4(%esp)
    movl    %edi, 8(%esp)
    movl    %eax, -24(%ebp)         # 4-byte Spill
    calll   *%ecx
    movl    -24(%ebp), %eax         # 4-byte Reload
    addl    $32, %esp
    popl    %esi
    popl    %edi
    popl    %ebp
    ret
.Ltmp0:
    .size   main, .Ltmp0-main


    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Note that the cpyfunc element is at offset 8 in the struct.

Edit: I did have to turn off optimizations because the ELLCC compiler (which is clang based) optimized the function to nothing with optimization turned on.

Comment: Aaah, figured it out now. That ELLCC compiler demo is actually pretty sweet for finding the memory position of stuff. The problem was that I treated my struct upside down. So I actually tried to run data instead of cpyfunc :)

Answer (score 0):

One way I've found to find out how to write something from C in Assembly is to see how the compiler does it. A C compiler will first internally convert your code into Assembly and then run the Assembler to create the object file.

You can usually pass in a flag to your compiler to create the intermediate assembly code. Do this, then take a look at how the C compiler calls the function pointers.

You can also run an objdump disassemble-all on your object file which is created by the compiler. This produces similar results.